# Find-and-replace perl regex including math

Tags: regex, perl, string-substitution

I'm working on a project and, due to a simple but very unfortunate mistake, need to rewrite a bunch of timestamps in a file; specifically, I need to take the final part of each timestamp and divide it by 30. For example, if the file contains:

`"blahblahblah[00:05:25]randomblah[01:22:13]"`

then i need it to say

`"bahblahblah[00:05:833]randomblah[01:22:433]"`

After realizing that pure regex can't handle the probem, as it only deals with character and not numbers, a little bit of googling pointed me toward a Perl one-liner, which I am trying to modify to fit my purposes. Here's what I have so far:

`perl -pi.bak -e 's/\d\d:\d\d:($1/30)!/e`

However, I have a syntax error `"around /30"`. Can anybody help with this, as well as elucidate how it works? I get the line-by-line stuff, but not the expression part. Thanks!

Comment: At a minimum you're going to run into the issue of the / being your delimiter character -- you're trying to do `s/<something>/e`, but you're giving perl `s/<something>/30/e`, which is too many arguments.  Try escaping that second slash: `($1\/30)`.

Comment: Do you want the numbers *rounded* or *truncated*? For instance, do you want to replace `[01:01:29]` with `[01:01:966]` or `[01:01:967]`? And what version of Perl are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed solution

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\d\d:\d\d:($1/30)!/e
```

doesn't work for a number of reasons; primarily that your substitution `s///` doesn't have two proper parameters. On the face of it you want to replace something that matches `\d\d:\d\d:($1` with `30)!`.

I'm not clear what you mean by the exclamation mark `!`, but I think you intended something more like

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's{(\d\d:\d\d:)(\d\d)}{$1.$2/30}eg'
```

which saves and restores the first two fields and divides the third field by 30. Unfortunately that's not quite right as it gives you

```
97blahblahblah[00:05:0.833333333333333]randomblah[01:22:0.433333333333333]
```

with your sample data.

So instead you need the first three digits of the quotient after dividing by 30. If you want the *closest* integer and you have a fairly recent version of Perl, this one-line solution should work for you. It prints the modified text to STDOUT. If you want to modifiy the file in-place then you can add `-i.bak` as in your own version.

```
perl -pe's{\d\d:\d\d:\K(\d\d)}{sprintf "%.0f", $1/30*1000}ge' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate delimiters, such as `s!!!`.  You need 2 capture groups: one for hours:minutes, and the other for the modified seconds.  You need to use the `g` modifier to change all instances on a line.  Refer to [s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/ in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = 'blahblahblah[00:05:25]randomblah[01:22:13]';
s!(\d{2}:\d{2}:)(\d{2})!$1 . int(1000*$2/30)!ge;
print "$_\n";

__END__

blahblahblah[00:05:833]randomblah[01:22:433]
```

Comment: The OP has a `perl -pe'...'` command line that doesn't work. I think this is too far removed to be very useful. Also `\d\d` is more brief than `\d{2}`, but the explicit semantics of the latter makes it a close call